# How do I filter a pyspark dataframe in a loop and append to a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a function that filters a pyspark dataframe by column value. I want to run it in a loop for different values and append the output for each loop in to a single dataframe. The code I have currently overwrites the dataframe for each loop. How do I get it to append instead of overwrite for each loop?

This is my pyspark dataframe (df):

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575        |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|227729        |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2  months of global news|
|228544        |2018-04-28 17:01:16|18 months of global news|
|231795        |2018-06-11 20:27:48|36 months of global news|
|234206        |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607        |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133        |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
|237883        |2018-08-07 18:52:53|1 months of global news | 
|237924        |2018-08-08 01:31:13|6 months of global news |
|238892        |2018-08-14 02:45:51|9 months of global news |
|242200        |2018-08-19 21:22:05|3 months of global news |
|249034        |2018-10-11 15:01:06|16 months of global news|
|254415        |2018-12-28 12:13:18|16 months of global news|
|257317        |2019-02-09 18:49:12|11 months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

This is my function to select products called '12 months of global news' for example

```
def renewal_filter(df, n):
    prod_type = str(n)+' months of global news'
    df_first_xmo = df.filter(df.product == prod_type)
    return df_first_xmo
```

If I call the function in a loop it overwrites the dataframe for each loop.

```
month = [12, 2]
for x in month:
    renewal_filter(df, x)
```

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575        |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|234206        |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607        |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133        |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+


+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|227729        |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2  months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

How might I change the loop logic to append instead of overwriting the dataframe on each loop so I could have this result?

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|user_id       |purchase_date_all  |product                 |
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
|226575        |2018-04-04 17:41:23|12 months of global news|
|234206        |2018-07-19 00:52:10|12 months of global news|
|234607        |2018-07-23 20:41:47|12 months of global news|
|235133        |2018-07-30 02:34:58|12 months of global news|
|227729        |2018-04-19 16:50:09|2  months of global news|
+--------------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I could not figure  how to concatenate from a loop in my post you shared here. Hoping I can figure out how to append via a loop. Unable to figure this out so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I give you totally different approach that does not need to union the dataframes.

```
month = [12, 2]

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('month', f.split('product', ' ')[0]) \
  .filter(f.col('month').isin(month)) \
  .show(10, False)

+-------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+
|user_id|purchase_date_all  |product                 |month|
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+
|228544 |2018-04-28 17:01:16|18 months of global news|18   |
|231795 |2018-06-11 20:27:48|36 months of global news|36   |
|237883 |2018-08-07 18:52:53|1 months of global news |1    |
|237924 |2018-08-08 01:31:13|6 months of global news |6    |
|238892 |2018-08-14 02:45:51|9 months of global news |9    |
|242200 |2018-08-19 21:22:05|3 months of global news |3    |
|249034 |2018-10-11 15:01:06|16 months of global news|16   |
|254415 |2018-12-28 12:13:18|16 months of global news|16   |
|257317 |2019-02-09 18:49:12|11 months of global news|11   |
+-------+-------------------+------------------------+-----+
```